# Access ID of view in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-ui-router, angularjs-routing

How can I access the `customerId` of a customer in the controller once the view got loaded?

**app.js:**

```
  $stateProvider.state('app.customer', {
    url: '/customer/:customerId',
    views: {
      'menuContent': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/customer.html',
        controller: 'CustomerCtrl'
      }
    }
  })
```

**customers.html:**

```
<a class="item item-points" ng-repeat="customer in customers" href="#/app/customer/{{customer.Customer.id}}"> ...
```

Comment: also consider using an ng-click with a Fn call to $state.go('route', {customerId: incomingCustomerId}); then you can reuse it across multiple links if needed (say in an ngRepeat). Other than that, inspect $stateParam in destination.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could get that in controller from the `$stateParams`, only you need to add the `$stateParams` dependency in your controller. Basically `$stateParams` will have all the parameters which are there in `URL`(in object)

```
$stateParams.customerId; //
```

I'll also recommend you to use `ui-sref` directive instead of creating URL by your own, that will create href with correct URL by looking at state.

```
<a class="item item-points" 
   ng-repeat="customer in customers" 
   ui-sref="app.customer({customerId : customer.Customer.id})">
  ...
</a>
```

Comment: Thx. The view loads (with the correct ID in the URL) but it looks like my controller in controller.js is not getting called. Any idea?

Comment: No, but my console.log() is not getting called at all.

Comment: could be anything! is your controller name CustomerCtrl as per your state config. Are you loading the controller. Are you assigning the controller to your app? does the app name match the name in the ng-app directive? etc etc

Answer (score 3):

In your controller inject `$stateParams`services

```
angular
  .module('yourmodule')
   .controller('CustomerCtrl',['$scope','$stateParams', function($scope, $stateParams){
     console.log($stateParams); //should be object {customerId: 'id-of-customer'}
  }])
```

Answer (score 2):

in the controller ...

```
$stateParams.customerId (injecting $stateParams service)
```

OR

```
$state.params.customerId (injecting $state service)
```

my preference is the 2nd approach since I use $state for things like $state.go etc and so it is easier to just use this